# jQuery mouseover on text and padding area not working

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have a wordpress blog, In the loop, the layout is like Text (Title. date, summary) on left and the image is float to right (padding 50% to left), i want to make the 50% space on left and all elements on this (Title. date, summary) to make hoverable (On hovering the left area make all text color change to black and background to #ff7f00;).

CSS of post-ut

```
  .post-ut {
    display:block;
    color:#999999; 
    z-index:2;
    float:left;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:13px;
    position: relative;
    width:282px;
}
.post-ut a {
    max-width:74px;
    min-width:74px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #999999;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Here is the idea of jQuery code i am using thats not working

```
    $('div.post-ut').mouseover(function() {


    $('.entry-summary p', $(this).parent())
       .css("color","black")
       .css("background","#ff7f00");

});

$('div.post-ut').mouseout(function() {

    $('.entry-summary p', $(this).parent())
       .css("color","white")
       .css("background","black");

});
```

The php code for wordress post loop is

```
<h1 class="thumb" style="z-index:2; width:252px;">
                    <a style="padding:15px 15px 5px 15px; width:252px; font-size:30px; font-weight:100; " href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', UT_THEME_NAME ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                </h1>

               <br/>

                <div class="post-ut" style="margin-top:-43px;"> 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php the_time('d. m. Y, g:i') ?> | <?php lambda_posted_in(); ?>                            
                </div> <!-- post by -->

            </header>

        <?php 

            echo '<div class="thumb" style="width:282px; padding-left:282px; margin-top:-114px; margin-bottom:20px; "><div class="post-image"><div class="overflow-hidden imagepost">';
            echo '<img class="wp-post-image"  style="display:inline-block; width:282px; height:272px;" src="'.$url.'" />';
            echo '<a title="'.get_the_title().'" href="'.get_permalink().'"><div class="hover-overlay"><span class="circle-hover"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/circle-hover.png" alt="'.__('link icon',UT_THEME_INITIAL).'" /></span></div></a>';
            echo '</div></div></div>';

        endif; ?>

        <div class="entry-content clearfix">



        <div class="entry-summary">

            <?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() || get_option_tree('excerpt_blog') == 'yes') : 

                the_excerpt(); 

            else : 
         ?>
           <?php endif; ?>   

        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

I am using the jquery to hover image, and thats working perfectly but not the code i posted above. The working code is

```
$('div.thumb').mouseover(function() {
$('a', $(this).parent())
   .css("color","black")
   .css("background","#ff7f00");

$('.post-ut', $(this).parent())
   .css("color","black")
   .css("background","#ff7f00")
   .find('a').css("color","black");

$('.entry-summary p', $(this).parent())
   .css("color","black")
   .css("background","#ff7f00");
```

});

```
$('div.thumb').mouseout(function() {

    $('a', $(this).parent())
       .css("color","white")
       .css("background","black");

    $('.post-ut', $(this).parent())
       .css("color","white")
       .css("background","black")
       .find('a').css("color","white");

    $('.entry-summary p', $(this).parent())
       .css("color","white")
       .css("background","black");

});
```

UPDATE: After Removing position:relative; from class post-ut, the hovering works but the text is not visible

Comment: "jQuery code i am using thats not working" What is not working? Any errors?

Comment: yes, when i hover the date --> (.post-ut) nothing happens, the background or color do not change of (.entry-summary p)

Comment: I cannot see <p> in .entry-summary in the code you posted but i don't know what the_excerpt() php's function returns

Comment: the_excerpt returns <div class="entry-summary p">blog summary</div>

Comment: So you have to use: $('.entry-summary.p', $(this).parent())

Comment: the_excerpt returns <div class="entry-summary p">blog summary</div>  I updated the question to include one more code that is working perfectly for image hover, but i want to make the left area also hover similarily as image

Comment: So what? Is p a tag or a class?

Comment: im already using  $('.entry-summary.p', $(this).parent()) but not working on hover p is a class

Comment: `<div class="entry-summary test-text">` should be `<div class="entry-summary p">` if that's the div you want to affect.

Comment: @TomL hi the text-test is blank class, thanks for pointing out, i have corrected the code, the issue is when i remove position:relative; from post-ut class, the jQuery hover code works but the text is not visible

Answer (score 0):

Remove p from code and check.

```
$('div.post-ut').mouseover(function() {

$('.entry-summary', $(this).parent())
   .css("color","black")
   .css("background","#ff7f00");

});

$('div.post-ut').mouseout(function() {

$('.entry-summary', $(this).parent())
   .css("color","white")
   .css("background","black");

});
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried but it did not work, when i hover post-ut nothing happens

Comment: Removing position:relative; from the css of class post-ut, hovering the date area works, but the text does not show